# Problema com XML LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

Estou com um pequeno problema com o meu *layout*.
Eu queria inserir um botão que ficaria no canto inferior no lado do direito do *layout*, mas quando faço isso o botão é adicionado a cada item da lista.

Obs: Essa lista é gerado por um banco de dados

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".BancoDados.Principal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_rest"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/l" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/nome" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_professor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/professor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_periodo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/periodo" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem que separar o *layout* dos itens da lista do *layout* da *Activity*

Comment: É mesmo como disse o @ramaral, tens de ter um *layout* `elemento_lista.xml` e outro *layout* para *Activity*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema... para ficar com o aspecto pretendido, deves criar dois ficheiros layout, um para os elemento da tua lista, e outro para a actividade.

O layout para cada elemento da tua lista seria qq coisa do tipo:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_rest"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/l" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/nome" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_professor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/professor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_periodo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/periodo" />

        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

O layout da tua actividade/fragmento seria:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Nas caracteristicas do botão acrescentei também **android:layout_gravity="right"**.
Se estiveres a construir a ListView com um Adapter só terás depois de fazer referência ao layout de cada item e a listview vai aparecer como pretendes.
Resumindo, tens de ter 2 ficheiros .xml em vez de um.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está colocando o `Button` dentro do item de sua lista e, quando você o infla, você irá ter um botão para cada item.

Para solucionar este problema, você deve remover o `Button` e o `LinearLayout` de seu xml (cada item da lista) e mover para sua `Activity` ou `Fragment` que contem o seu `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/placeholder_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no meu caso esta um pouco complicado, pois o banco de dados automaticamente cria um lista.

Comment: Mas você passa esse arquivo xml em algum lugar para criar esta lista, correto? E em algum lugar essa `ListView` precisa estar declarada. Se puder colocar trechos de código, ajudaria!

Comment: O meu banco de dados é baseado neste: https://mega.co.nz/#!LBUW3KaQ!fqzesccUGZkweHGaMS45Xm2qPz_zYon8t4EdhoJ9Qjw

Comment: O problema é que no exemplo dado, está utilizando uma `ListActivity`. Para utilizar o que você quer, deverá trocar para uma `Activity` padrão e utilizar uma `ListView` dentro dela.